# How to graph data from a Raspberry Pi in real-time on a webpage?

Tags: javascript, python, raspberry-pi, iot, dashboard

I have a script on a raspberry pi that collects ambient light sensor data in lux. It currently sends that data to [Ubidots](https://ubidots.com/docs/hw/#send-data) via an http post request. It graphs this data with lux on the y axis and seconds on the x axis. I'm trying to build a dashboard myself because Ubidots can't be used for commercial purposes. I've currently converted the data in the python file to make a csv and used the Fetch api to graph it. This is good for the time being however I want to be able to see the graph occur in real time. How would I go about sending and graphing this data in **real time**.

Answer (score 0):

You need to have a whole IoT architecture, if you are talking about having a production ready solution here. For example you could use some IoT related services from different cloud providers like AWS, Google cloud platform. Lets say you would like to use Google cloud platform. Then you can use Google IoT core, Pub/Sub, Cloud Function with some databases like Bigquery/Google Datastore for your backend. For realtime data either you can use Redis or some other databases with cache and then in the end you could use some frontend framework React or Vue etc.